# Angular JS should take pre-defined list of values as Url Parameter

Tags: angularjs

What i am trying to implement:

param value should be one of a,b,c,d,e. If the param value is not in the given list of values, user should be redirected.

This implementation is giving me "Infinite $digest Loop" error. How can i make this work?

```
$routeProvider
        .when("/:param", {
            templateUrl: function(params){
                if($.inArray(params.param, ["a","b","c","d","e"]) > -1)
                    return "templates/index.html";
                else
                    location.replace("#/a");
            },
            controller: 'F'
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it in your route configuration, you could try and do it in your controller. The following code assumes that provided route parameters are `?a=value&b=value`:

```
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $location) {
    var currentParams = $location.search(); // { a: 'value', b: 'value' }

    // if all required params are not present, use `$location.replace`
});
```

Comment: Looks like the way to go. However i will keep this question open for now  for other suggestions as well. Thanks for helping. :)